# A simple way to use Harvard referencing in my article

Tags: citing, natbib, harvard-style

I have a `.bib` file where I have put all  my references in the format such as follows:

```
@article{chiambaretto2019,
  title   = "All for One and One for All? - Knowledge broker roles in managing tensions of internal coopetition: The Ubisoft case",
  journal = "Research Policy",
  volume  = "48",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "584-600",
  year    = "2019",
  doi     = "10.1016/j.respol.2018.10.009",
  author  = "Paul Chiambaretto and David Masse and Nicola Mirc"
}
```

I have previously prepared the paper in the LaTeX format of a journal (which had a perfect template with its own `bibliographystyle .bst` file), which it was rejected. Unfortunately, the new journal I am trying to submit to does not have any ready template (one of the Emerald journals) and it has requested for the references to be in `harvard` style. Whatever I do, I cannot change the already to `harvard` and I get several  errors every time which I searched  them step  by step in `tex.stackexchange` but  every time a new error rises. What can I do so I can use the `harvard` style on my `.bib` file with changing the least parts of my `.tex` file?

These are the code after `\documentclass`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}

\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlgreen}[1]{{\sethlcolor{green}\hl{#1}}}

\usepackage{natbib}
    \setcitestyle{authoryear,round,aysep={}}
```

Also in the `\begin{document}`:

```
\bibliography{mybibMD}
```

Also I used the commands `\citep` and `\citet` in the previous journal's template which was awesome and so helpful. But dont seem to be working in `harvard` style.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that "Harvard style" is not a fully well-defined term in the same way as "APA style" or "Chicago style" are. "Harvard style" generally only means author-year citations, most other bits are up for interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/administration-and-support-services/library/public/LaTeX-example-Harvard-apr-2019.pdf).

In short, you want to use `natbib` (which you do) with `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`, and remove the `\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,aysep={}}`.

`\bibliographystyle{agsm}` does everything you want :).

PS: Try to post a working example. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybibMD.bib}
@article{chiambaretto2019,
  title   = "All for One and One for All? - Knowledge broker roles in managing tensions of internal coopetition: The Ubisoft case",
  journal = "Research Policy",
  volume  = "48",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "584-600",
  year    = "2019",
  doi     = "10.1016/j.respol.2018.10.009",
  author  = "Paul Chiambaretto and David Masse and Nicola Mirc"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
 

bla bla \citep{chiambaretto2019} 

ha? \citet{chiambaretto2019}


\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{mybibMD}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But still there is a problem. The harvard format is like "Capizzi, M.T. and Ferguson, R. (2005), "Loyalty trends for the twenty-first century", Journal of Consumer Marketing, Vol. 22 No. 2, pp.72-80." But in my file it showing like this: "Capizzi, M.T. and Ferguson, R. (2005), "Loyalty trends for the twenty-first century", Journal of Consumer Marketing, 22(4), 72-80." It is not showing the phrase "Vol.", "No.", "pp." and  also mine  the title is italic and volume number is bold which is not the case  in harvard

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks.

Comment: If it's not exactly the same ... you can always use: makebst (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/custom-bib/makebst.pdf) -> call  `latex makebst`
It will ask you a lot of questions, but you can make your own style.